# How to add External Content type To custom SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs, external-content-type

We have a requirement Creating External Content type in sharpoint 2013 based on that SQL database Table.

For example in sql i have four database(db1,db2,db3,db4) and sharepoint i have 4 custom list(list1,list2,list3,list4).

db1 having 4 columns

Same data are in sharepoint list1(Customlist Name : Employeedatabase) also but exept PhoneNumber column.

So i need to add this Phone Number column to Employeedatabase custom list through External content type.

when i add this External Content Type to Employeedatabase custom list PhoneNumber column should be added and Based on that EMPID in that same row PhoneNumber should be update.

How i can achieve this through code without using sharepoint designer?

This is just example like that we are having more database with more columns.
Please anyone share sample code snippet or any link for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using external lists for that? When you say custom list, are you really referring to custom SharePoint list?

Comment: Already we are having more than 100 Custom List in our site.So in existing site only we need to add external content type.

Comment: What's the relationship between this content type and the nature of the existing custom list? Is there a specific need to add it to the list?

Comment: Yes, actually in our site SharePoint list does not contain all database(sql) & columns.So manually we can't find which list missing which column.So using sql database we are creating ECT then add this ECT to particular list.

Comment: Client need this requirement. i searched lot But i did'd find anything , so its possible ?Are you getting my question ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.. that's why I was thinking with you about the need itself and how to approach it differently, because it doesn't seem right to do it this way. It seems you're transferring data from SQL into SharePoint lists, and lists are not managed well and their schema isn't clear.

Comment: But you can wait for other people to contribute and give you ideas as well. I am just wondering when you say the list doesn't contain database columns, are you trying to replicate what's in SQL into SharePoint..?

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Can you explain more why are you moving data from SQL into SharePoint, if you can clarify more..

Comment: Yes Some columns are missing in SharePoint list comparing to SQL database so i need to add missed column in SharePoint list with data.

Comment: Before client are using SQL database.Then they are moving to SharePoint.Now they are keeping there data to SharePoint list.

So now they want to move there existing SQL data to SharePoint with existing list

Comment: They don't want to use SQL anymore, or they want to keep storing data in sql as well?

Comment: They want to keep data in sql also, they did any changes in sql database it should reflect to SharePoint list, In SharePoint list they are change data that will reflect to Sql.

Comment: using SharePoint designer i was created ECT for sql table and added one external list. So any changes i add a new item to sql it will added to sharepoint external  list, In sharepoint list i added new item it will adding to sql database. 

This same functionality i need to implement for excisting  Custom list

Comment: OK then. So you should create the external list, it will be mapped with the sql table. And for any data newly added to the custom list and not added to the external list/database, then create a powershell script to compare items between the 2 lists and move the items (copy/create new item in external list) to fill the gap. Then just keep using the external list and delete the custom list.

Comment: we cant't do like that because they are having more than 300 list. For that 300 list again we can't create 300 external list.

Client they won't accept to delete custom list.

Comment: How are you making sure that the data from SQL is populated in custom lists? What if later you have 1000 lists, are you going to keep these workarounds to get them populated? Anyway, I suggest finding a straightforward solution from the start, beginning with SQL to SharePoint, before thinking about the custom lists..

Comment: Any other way is there Creating timerjob and when the sql database updated the timerjob to check and update to the sharepoint list.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the steps to be followed in SharePoint Designer to achieve your desired result.

[SharePoint 2013: BDC Configuration And Creating External Content Type and External List](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-bdc-configuration-and-creating-external-con2/)

**UPDATED**

[SharePoint List From SQL Server Table (External Content Type with SharePoint Designer)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mind_talks/2012/04/03/sharepoint-list-from-sql-server-table-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer/)

Please let me know if you need some more help.

Thanks.

Comment: this is for Extrenal list hardik. I need to add External Content type to already existing custom list. Sharepoint and SQL both should communicate. Any data added to sharepoint list it will come to SQL. From sql i added new item it will added to Sharepoint list

Comment: Is there any way to add External content type to custom list?

Comment: Hi hardik using timer job we can integrate SQL to SharePoint  list  ?

Comment: Please check here if you can get something for you...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mind_talks/2012/04/03/sharepoint-list-from-sql-server-table-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Already i referred this, you have any idea about timer job to integrate sql to sharepoint ?

Comment: you can establish your database connection in Execute method. If you want to specify your database connection string in config file, then you need to use owstimer.exe.config. This is present in BIN folder under 12\14\15 hive based on version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: Any reference link can you please share with me.

Comment: There might not be any reference link available as I have already searched for the same. But you understand the approach... Right?

Comment: ya,i understand but any reference is there means it might be helpful for me tats why i asked you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39731/discussion-between-hardik-and-kavitha).